# python pandas task

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data set like this

```
event_date | user_id | user_city | user_state |
06-09-2021 | 23      | Thane     | Maharashtra
04-09-2021 | 3224    | Madurai   | Tamil Nadu
02-08-2021 | 2331    | Ghaziabad | Utter Pradesh
```

using pandas python I want output in this format

```
User ID | Date of      | Location of  |  Location of  | Location on Second | 
        | Last Logins  | Latest Login |  Max Logins   | Most Login         |
        |              |              |               |                    |
5       | 11-09-2021   |  Gurgaon     |  Meerut       |  Noida             |
```

Comment: where is the login data

Comment: why u need login data

Comment: in your output you have login data, which is not in the original table

Comment: @trillion I believe it is orginal data, he may be changed the column names of `event_date` and `user_city`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: why do you have just id 5 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`pandas.DataFrame.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) and [`pandas.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and return [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) after applying [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with new column names.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['06-28-2021',23  ,'Thane','Maharashtra'],
    ['06-12-2021',23  ,'TEST','Maharashtra'],
    ['06-11-2021',23  ,'TEST','Maharashtra'],
    ['04-09-2021',3224,'Madurai','Tamil Nadu'],
    ['02-08-2021',2331,'Ghaziabad','Utter Pradesh']],
    columns=['event_date', 'user_id', 'user_city', 'user_state'])
df['event_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_date'])
def func(g):
    last_row = g.iloc[-1]
    cities = g['user_city'].value_counts().nlargest(2).index
    cols = ['Date of last login','Location of Latest Logins','Location of Last Logins','Location on Second Most Login']
    return pd.Series((last_row['event_date'],last_row['user_city'],cities[0],cities[-1]), index=cols)
new_df = df.sort_values('event_date').groupby('user_id').apply(func)
print(new_df)
```

| user_id | Date of last login | Location of last login | Location of most login | Location on 2nd Most Login |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 2021-06-28 00:00:00 | Thane | TEST | Thane |
| 2331 | 2021-02-08 00:00:00 | Ghaziabad | Ghaziabad | Ghaziabad |
| 3224 | 2021-04-09 00:00:00 | Madurai | Madurai | Madurai |

**METHOD 2**

Get the largest date using [`pandas.DataFrame.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html) without sorting the dataframe (i.e You can avoid using the `df.sort_values('event_date')`)

Note : For some case sort_values will be faster to avoid the overhead of accessing nlargest in every iteration.

```
def func(g):
    last_login = df.iloc[g['event_date'].nlargest(1).index[0]]
    cities = g['user_city'].value_counts().nlargest(2).index
    cols = ['Date of last login','Location of Latest Logins','Location of Last Logins','Location on Second Most Login']
    return pd.Series((last_login['event_date'],last_login['user_city'],cities[0],cities[-1]), index=cols)
```

*Please let me know if my codes does not meet your expected result.*

Comment: @LandLord Can you please update me the error you got?